# How to get the value from JSON in Android?

Tags: android, json

I am develop in `Android and Xively.`

I get the `JSON data` like the following.

```
{"id":10541167124,"title":"air-conditioner","private":"false","feed":"https://api.xively.com/v2/feeds/10541167124.json","status":"frozen","updated":"2014-08-15T08:23:01.612382Z","created":"2014-08-15T08:17:17.336198Z","creator":"https://xively.com/users/x22819","version":"1.0.0","datastreams":[{"id":"air-aonditioner1","current_value":"25","at":"2014-08-15T08:23:01.521837Z","max_value":"25.0","min_value":"25.0","tags":["air=off","eco=off","freeze_proofing=off","power=on","stop_time=1","temp_set=24","wind_speed=low"],"unit":{"symbol":"C","label":"Celsius"}}],"product_id":"uq8_wTGk4Kdmfmlaa1B-","device_serial":"7AHJ84EAQDEZ"}
```

I use the following code to get the `tags` data.

```
 String resultJSON = response.getContent();
try {
    JSONObject jsonRoot = new JSONObject(resultJSON);
    JSONArray jsonData = jsonRoot.getJSONArray("datastreams");
    for(int i=0 ; i < jsonData.length() ; i++)
    {

        JSONObject jsonOBject = jsonData.getJSONObject(i);
        String tags = jsonOBject.getString("tags");
        Log.(TAG, "tags = "+ tags + "\n");

    }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();


    }
```

The data of `tags` is like the following

```
D/DemoActivity(25686): tags = ["air=off","eco=off","freeze_proofing=off","power=on","stop_time=1","temp_set=24","wind_speed=low"]
```

But I want to get the more detail value in `tags` , for example : air is ? power is ? temp_set is ?

**How do I get the more detail data in `tags` ?**

Comment: in your for loop add JSONObject json = new JSONObject(tags); after getString tags.then you can get anything like String air = json.getString(air);

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the text result of `tags` to the constructor of `JSON class` and iterate on it while replacing all the `"="` of each string to `" is "`

**sample:**

```
    for(int i=0 ; i < jsonData.length() ; i++)
    {

        JSONObject jsonOBject = jsonData.getJSONObject(i);
        String tags = jsonOBject.getString("tags");
        JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(tags);
        for(int i = 0 ; i < arr.length(); i++)
            Log.d("VALUE", arr.getString(i).replaceAll("=", " is "));

    }
```

**result:**

```
08-19 01:43:32.169: D/VALUE(1444): air is off
08-19 01:43:32.169: D/VALUE(1444): eco is off
08-19 01:43:32.175: D/VALUE(1444): freeze_proofing is off
08-19 01:43:32.175: D/VALUE(1444): power is on
08-19 01:43:32.175: D/VALUE(1444): stop_time is 1
08-19 01:43:32.189: D/VALUE(1444): temp_set is 24
08-19 01:43:32.195: D/VALUE(1444): wind_speed is low
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
try{
   String jsonResponse = "{\"id\":10541167124,\"title\":\"air-conditioner\",\"private\":\"false\",\"feed\":\"https://api.xively.com/v2/feeds/10541167124.json\",\"status\":\"frozen\",\"updated\":\"2014-08-15T08:23:01.612382Z\",\"created\":\"2014-08-15T08:17:17.336198Z\",\"creator\":\"https://xively.com/users/x22819\",\"version\":\"1.0.0\",\"datastreams\":[{\"id\":\"air-aonditioner1\",\"current_value\":\"25\",\"at\":\"2014-08-15T08:23:01.521837Z\",\"max_value\":\"25.0\",\"min_value\":\"25.0\",\"tags\":[\"air=off\",\"eco=off\",\"freeze_proofing=off\",\"power=on\",\"stop_time=1\",\"temp_set=24\",\"wind_speed=low\"],\"unit\":{\"symbol\":\"C\",\"label\":\"Celsius\"}}],\"product_id\":\"uq8_wTGk4Kdmfmlaa1B-\",\"device_serial\":\"7AHJ84EAQDEZ\"}";

   JSONObject dataJson = new JSONObject(jsonResponse);
   HashMap<String,Object> row = new HashMap<String, Object>();
   row.put("id", dataJson.getString("id"));
   row.put("title",dataJson.getString("title"));
   row.put("private",dataJson.getString("private"));
   row.put("feed",dataJson.getString("feed"));
   row.put("status",dataJson.getString("status"));
   row.put("updated",dataJson.getString("updated"));
   row.put("created",dataJson.getString("created"));
   row.put("creator",dataJson.getString("creator"));
   row.put("version",dataJson.getString("version"));
   ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> datastreamsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
   JSONArray datastreamsjsonArray = dataJson.getJSONArray("datastreams");
   for (int i=0;i<datastreamsjsonArray.length();i++){
       HashMap<String,Object> datastreamsMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
       datastreamsMap.put("id",datastreamsjsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("id"));
       datastreamsMap.put("current_value",datastreamsjsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("current_value"));
       datastreamsMap.put("at",datastreamsjsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("at"));
       datastreamsMap.put("max_value",datastreamsjsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("max_value"));
       datastreamsMap.put("min_value",datastreamsjsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("min_value"));
       JSONArray tagsJsonArray = datastreamsjsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("tags");
       ArrayList<String> tagsList = new ArrayList<String>();
       for (int j=0;j<tagsJsonArray.length();j++){
            tagsList.add(tagsJsonArray.getString(j));
       }
       datastreamsMap.put("tags",tagsList);
       HashMap<String,String> unitMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
       unitMap.put("symbol",datastreamsjsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("unit").getString("symbol"));
       unitMap.put("label",datastreamsjsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("unit").getString("label"));
       datastreamsMap.put("unit",unitMap);

       datastreamsList.add(datastreamsMap);
    }
    row.put("datastreams",datastreamsList);
    row.put("product_id",dataJson.getString("product_id"));
    row.put("device_serial",dataJson.getString("device_serial"));

    System.out.print("id :"+row.get("id"));
    System.out.print("title :"+row.get("title"));
    System.out.print("private :"+row.get("private"));
    System.out.print("feed :"+row.get("feed"));
    System.out.print("status :"+row.get("status"));
    System.out.print("updated :"+row.get("updated"));
    System.out.print("created :"+row.get("created"));
    System.out.print("creator :"+row.get("creator"));
    System.out.print("version :"+row.get("version"));
    ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>> datastreamsListData = (ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>)row.get("datastreams");
    for (int i=0;i<datastreamsListData.size();i++){
         HashMap<String,Object> datastreamsMapData = datastreamsListData.get(i);
         System.out.print("id :" + datastreamsMapData.get("id"));
         System.out.print("current_value :" + datastreamsMapData.get("current_value"));
         System.out.print("at :"+datastreamsMapData.get("at"));
         System.out.print("max_value :" + datastreamsMapData.get("max_value"));
         System.out.print("min_value :"+datastreamsMapData.get("min_value"));
         ArrayList<String> tagsListData = (ArrayList<String>) datastreamsMapData.get("tags");
         for (int j=0;j<tagsListData.size();j++){
              System.out.print(tagsListData.get(j));
         }
         HashMap<String,Object> unitMapData = (HashMap<String,Object>) datastreamsMapData.get("unit");
         System.out.print("symbol :"+unitMapData.get("symbol"));
         System.out.print("label :"+unitMapData.get("label"));

     }
     System.out.print("product_id :"+row.get("product_id"));
     System.out.print("device_serial :"+row.get("device_serial"));

}catch (Throwable e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that tags are inside a JSONArray, so use the following code instead:

```
    try {
        JSONObject jsonRoot = new JSONObject(resultJSON);
        JSONArray jsonData = jsonRoot.getJSONArray("datastreams");
        for (int i = 0 ; i < jsonData.length() ; i++) {
            JSONObject jsonOBject = jsonData.getJSONObject(i);
            JSONArray  arrTags = jsonOBject.getJSONArray("tags");
            for (int j = 0; j < arrTags.length(); j++) {
                Log.i("Array Tag [ "+ i +" ] ", arrTags.opt(j).toString());
            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```